# Como faço para mostrar os nomes e as notas de um array em java?

Tags: java

sou iniciante em Java e resolvi criar esse exercício para testar meus conhecimentos, só que estou quebrando muito a cabeça para mostrar os valores desse Array. Quero que  no final da execução, ele mostre o nome do aluno com suas respectivas notas, tentei fazer um for  só que não deu muito certo. Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato!  Quero o seguinte resultado no final da execução:

Nome: Aluno1
Nota1:
Nota2:

Nome: Aluno2
Nota1:
Nota2:

```
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    double numero[] = new double[2];
    String nome[] = new String[2];

    for (int contador = 0; contador < nome.length; contador++) {
        System.out.println("Nome " + (contador + 1));
        nome[contador] = entrada.next();

        for (int cont = 0; cont < numero.length; cont++) {

            System.out.println("Informe a " + (cont + 1) + "° nota: ");
            numero[cont] = entrada.nextDouble();

        }

    }

    for (int cont = 0; cont < nome.length; cont++) {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + (cont + 1) + " " + nome[cont]);
        for (int conta = 0; conta < numero.length; conta++) {

            System.out.println("nota " + (conta + 1) + " " + numero[conta]);

        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, perceba que, em seu código, após adicionar um aluno, você pede as notas, certo? Bom, para o primeiro caso, isso funciona. Porém, ao inserir o segundo aluno, como você está utilizando o mesmo array "numero", ele sobrescreve as notas do primeiro aluno com a do segundo aluno. Não há como printar separadamente, após a inserção, as notas dos dois alunos. Elas sempre sairão iguais.

Sugiro que você ou crie um outro array de notas para o segundo aluno, ou crie uma classe de aluno, a qual, dentro dela, possua esse array de duas notas. Se ainda não aprendeu sobre classes, faça um outro array para armazenar as duas notas desse segundo aluno.